# Highlighting entire table row if validation fails

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am working on JSF2.0 and Richfaces.  I am having an requirement where I need to change the style of the form field(entire row) if the validation fails.  I am using the following code to display field label and text box.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel value="#{uit.firstname}:">
                <span class="required"><strong>*</strong> </span>
            </h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText value="#{editUserProfileBean.firstName}" type="text"
                    id="firstname" styleClass="basicFormTextBox" size="30"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="#{uitkem.valueRequired}"
                    validatorMessage="#{prod.firstNameValidator}">
                    <f:validateLength maximum="#{prodConf.MaxLengthForFirstName}"
                        minimum="#{prodConf.MinLengthForFirstName}" />
                    <f:validator validatorId="trimSpaces" />
                </h:inputText>
            </h:panelGrid>
```

Suppose if the validation fails, I need to hightlight the row(both label and textbox).

I can use the following code to hightlight the textbox if the validation fails.  But I want to hightlight the entire row, that is not possible using the following code.

```
    <h:inputText value="#{editUserProfileBean.firstName}" required="true" styleClass="#{not component.valid ? 'newStyleClass' : ''}" />
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could just write a tiny JS script with jQuery, or use `<rich:jQuery>` for that.